# Redirect .style.css page and website should load css

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess

Let me explain scenario.
The style.css path has been set as-
https (colon)// xyz dot com/main/css/style.css

As style.css is file readable in browser I want to block the access at the same time website pages should load css.

Things tried so far-
1) If I block access to /style.css file in httpd.conf then css doesn't load and website opens up without theme and styles.
2) If I redirect /style.css to /main in .htaccess then again website loads without theme and styles.

I would appreciate a guidance in layman's language as am still learning and even after referring to many posts on stackoverflow; unfortunately couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your css files need to be accessed by the browser. Then they will also be available for the users. It's inevitable. You can't allow access to the browser and block them to users.

If you want to protect your work, you can obfuscate them with a tool such as http://cssobfuscator.com/ or integrate it directly in your [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) build with e.g. [gulp-css-gsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-gsub). They will be usable by the browser but it will be difficult to reuse them.

Comment: Ok, Any alternate option, like change in path of css directory? As I said, I want to protect .css from public view so pls suggest accordingly.

Comment: If you protect css files from public view, they will not be used by the browser. Is it what you want?

Comment: No, I can't afford that. But obfuscation is the only way to lower risk, I thought I could eliminate it completely either by redirecting to home page or to some error page.

Comment: Hi, can I include this in my build process using gulp

Comment: Yes, you can with for example [gulp-css-gsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-gsub).